# rvalue not working for reference

Tags: c++, reference, lvalue, rvalue

I was studying about references and i was trying a program to pass an rvalue to a function as reference argument, like this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int &x)
{
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    cout << fun(10);
    return 0;
}
```

but this didn't work, when i tried to pass an lvalue, It worked.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int &x)
{
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    int x=10;
    cout << fun(x);
    return 0;
}
```

can someone explain me why this happens?

Comment: What do you need to do with the rvalue that requires changing it?

Comment: It's the same with pointers, you wouldn't expect to be able to get a pointer to the literal `10` would you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An *rvalue* can only bind to an *rvalue* reference or a `const` *lvalue* reference; not to a non-const *lvalue* reference. So either of these would work:

```
int fun(int const & x);
int fun(int && x);
```

This is to prevent surprising behaviour where a function might modify a temporary value instead of the variable you thought it might; for example:

```
void change(int & x) {++x;}

long x = 42;
change(x);
cout << x;   // would print 42: would have changed a temporary 'int', not 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass reference in your `fun(int &x)`. the `&` sign means "Passing argument address/reference". Currently you are trying to mix modifiable lvalue and constant rvalue, which is wrong 
`fun(const int &x)` will work just fine, this is probably what you want to do. See [this](http://ideone.com/D7NENQ)